# Put content in a file with text

Tags: php

I need help adding Before and After text to a file as its created with php ... I am using this code

```
    $text = "start";
    $text2 = "stop";
  $stream1 =  $text . file_put_contents("flename.txt", $stream) .$text2 ;
```

Its adding the info not the filename.txt and creating it but the start and stop before and after text does not get added any idea whats going on? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get the content from a file then you will append the text before and after the old content and save it again:

```
$text_before = "start";
$text_after = "stop";

$content = $text_before .$stream .$text_after;

file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

`$your_text` variable is the text you already have

Comment: I already have the content to be added to the file it adds that i just want to add text before and after it

Comment: The text i already have it a code i grabbed using Getstring under $stream

Comment: !$text_before = "start";
$text_after = "stop";

$content = $text_before .$stream .$text_after;

file_put_contents($filename, $content);~

Comment: Maybe? like that